# Need an IFF statement to work where the data is not in a joining table, so it is not labeled as NULL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
ATO.Agent,
ATO.Bottler_ID,
ATO.Account_number,
ATO.DELIVERY_DATE, 
IFF (ATO.Account_number IS NULL,0,1) AS Opportunity
from ATO
left join OOM on ATO.Account_number = OOM.Account_number
```

The Account number will not be NULL, If it does not appear in the OOM table, I just want a "0" in a new Opportunity column, but if it IS there, I need a 1.

Answer (score 1):

just use a CASE statement to implement the logic based on OOM.Account_number being null or not

Answer (score 0):

This query does a left join and replaces nulls joins with the desired logic:

```sql
with data as (select $1 id, $2 name from values(1,'a'), (2,'b') )
, reference as (select $1 id from values(1))

select a.*, iff(b.id is null, 'no ref', 'has ref')
from data a
left join reference b
on a.id=b.id
```

[image]

The query you posted should work as expected. Can you show us what results you get, and what results you expect?

Comment: If the ATO.Account number is in the OOM table, I need the Opportunity column to show a "1", if it is not in the OOM table, I need there to be a "0."  I believe the way I have it written, it will only look for "NULL", not whether or not the account number is in the table.    I need the outcome to be Agent Account Date Opportunity
Jane 415959 16-Jul-21 1
Jane 415959 23-Jul-21 1
Jane 627005 12-Jul-21 1
Jane 822902 20-Jul-21 0
Jane 824531 14-Jul-21 1
Jane 919281 29-Jul-21 0

Comment: I am currently getting all "1"'s in the Opportunity column

Comment: Please, can you add some sample data on the question to test it with different data?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help - the problem was actually in my OOM table. Git it working now.